# Subgroup generated by $2$ and $7$ in $(\mathbb Z,+)$

Tags: group-theory

In group $(\mathbb Z,+)$ , the subgroup generated by $2$ and $7$ is

1. $\mathbb Z$
2. $5\mathbb Z$
3. $9\mathbb Z$
4. $14\mathbb Z$

In general what's the result for any $n$, $m$ instead of $2$ and $7$.

I think it should be $\gcd(n, m)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Hint: Note that $\gcd(2, 7) = 1$. Your on the right path with your thoughts about the general case: $m, n$ generate $\gcd(m,n)\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes! That's right. $\left<m, n \right> = \left<d\right>$ where $d =$ gcd$(m,n).$

Comment: Very fine. So my textbook is wrong it writes lcm instead of gcd. Thanks

Comment: Yes, if they are not both $0$ it is the group of multiples of the gcd.  For the proof, use the fact that there exist integers $x$ and $y$  such that $mx+ny$ is the gcd.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Note that $\gcd(2, 7) = 1$.

Your on the right path with your thoughts about the general case. Indeed, for integers $m, n$ (not both zero), $$\langle m, n\rangle = \gcd(m, n)\mathbb Z$$

In this case, that means that $$\langle 2, 7\rangle = \gcd(2, 7)\mathbb Z = \mathbb 1\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$$

Comment: This Q have been asked in a competitive exam and they have given option d (I.e. $\mathbb{14Z}$) as correct answer in the official answer key. Please clear it to me so that I can claim my answer.

Comment: Yes bro,they are asking for book refference...we need a proper proof,I also gave this up PGT exam on 18 August!

Comment: Have you claimed it?

Answer (score -2):

The answer is $14z$ because $(\mathbb {Z}, +)$ is an abelian group so in any abelian group if order of $2$ elements is given then the order of their product will be l.c.m of that numbers

So
$$\text{l.c.m}(2, 7) =14$$

Comment: Sorry there was l.c.m(2, 7) Z= 14Z